# Prove the Cayley's formula for the number of trees using recursion

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I started to look at the Cayley's formula for the number of trees and the ways to prove it.
I have looked at the prove by bijection and now I get it.
I started to look at how to prove the Cayley's formula by recursion.
I've downloaded a material in pdf and I'm trying to understand the last part "A forest of trees".
What I don't understand is how did they come up with this:
$$
   T_{n,k} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i}T_{n-1,(k-1)+i}
$$
Can anyone give me a better explanation or give me another material?

Link to the pdf material: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Casarotto.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put vertices 1 through $k$ in one line, and the remaining $n-k$ vertices in a line below them.  Since the top $k$ vertices have to be in their own tree, there will be no edges between any of them. Consider vertex 1. It can be adjacent to $i$ of the lower vertices, where $0 \le i \le n-k$. None of those $i$ vertices will be adjacent to each other, otherwise there would be a cycle through vertex 1. None of the vertices 2 through $k$ will be adjacent to any of these $i$ vertices either, since all of the top vertices have to be in their own tree. If we delete vertex 1, we now have $n-1$ vertices. We originally had $k$ upper vertices that had to be in their own tree, now we have $k-1$ upper vertices that have to be in their own tree. The $i$ neighbors of 1 also have to be in their own tree, since there are no edges between themselves or between upper vertices 2 through $k$. Thus we have $k-1+i$ vertices that have to be in their own tree, which means we're in the $T_{n-1, k-1+i}$ case. Since this all depends on the $i$ neighbors of 1, we have to sum over all possible choices for those neighbors. There are $n-k$ neighbors to choose from, and we're choosing $i$ of them. That's where the binomial coefficient is coming from.

Comment: Let's say n=4 and k=2.Then n-k=2.We know that n=k+i(maximum number of i).But I don't understand what happens to the other 2 nodes when i=0?

Comment: When $i=0$, we have 1 is isolated and there is some path containing 2, 3 and 4. When we delete 1 and relabel the vertices, we see we're in the case $T_{3,1}$.

Comment: Let's take an example.Let's say n={1,2,3,4} and A={1,2}.When i=1 then there are 2 choices for i and so two labels for it(for example 3 and 4).Now when we construct $$ T_{n-1,(k-1)+i} $$ It becomes $$  T_{3,2} $$.If we draw this what will be the label for k.Will it be 2,3 and then 2,4 or what ?

Comment: It depends, as there are several of graphs to consider in the $T_{4,2}$ case when $i=1$. For example, we could have $E=\{\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$ or $E=\{\{1,3\}, \{3,4\}\}$.

Comment: "If we delete vertex 1"-- why is this deletion necessary? What does it mean? I mean, what are we actually looking into by deleting vertex 1?